Why is the PSD of AWGN often represented as _0/2 instead of just _0?
I've been studying digital communication systems, and I understand that (N_0) represents the power spectral density (PSD) of Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN). However, I've encountered several sources that refer to the PSD of AWGN as (N_0/2) when analyzing systems like BPSK and QPSK. This confuses me because I thought (N_0) already represents the PSD of the noise.

Can someone explain why the PSD of AWGN is sometimes expressed as (N_0/2) instead of (N_0)? Does this have to do with the division of noise power between in-phase and quadrature components, or is there another reason?

Any detailed clarification or references to specific textbook sections would be greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question PSD of complex white gaussian noise?

@DanBoschen I don't think that that particulatr question and its answers are all that relevant to the question being asked here.

@DilipSarwate I suspect you didn't read my answer that I linked. The question posted there was specific to complex numbers, but my answer provides both cases as to when we see No/2 used - what you answered here (is mentioned there) as well as the case that the OP provides. Both are valid explanations and useful considerations for and answer to this question. See slide 8 in this link that also shows how the real and imaginary components are No/2: https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~sarva/courses/EE703/2022/slides/OptimalReceiverInAWGNComplex.pdf

$N_0$ (measured in volts$^2$ per Hertz or watts per Hertz) is the power spectral density of white noise for those who don't believe in the existence of negative frequencies, and leads to simple calculations such as the noise power at the output of an ideal (unit-gain) lowpass filter  of bandwidth $B$ is $N_0B$. But those who believe in negative frequencies and for whom the transfer function of the ideal (unit-gain) lowpass filter has value $1$ for all $f \in [-B,+B]$, the value of the power spectral density of the white noise to set to be $\dfrac{N_0}2$, so that the noise power at the output of the filter is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{N_0}2 \cdot|H(f)|^2 \,\mathrm df = \int_{-B}^B \frac{N_0}2 \cdot 1 \,\mathrm df = N_0B$$ just as for those who don't believe in negative frequencies.
Similarly for ideal bandpass filters of bandwidth $B$ whose transfer functions have value $1$ for all $f \in \left[f_c-\frac B2, f_c+\frac B2\right]$ for positivists and value $1$ for all $f \in \left[f_c-\frac B2, f_c+\frac B2\right] \bigcup \left[-f_c-\frac B2, -f_c+\frac B2\right]$ for those with negative attitudes: the noise power at the output of the ideal bandpass filter is given by $N_0B$ and is obtained by integrating $N_0$ times the power transfer function $|H(f)|^2$ over $f \in \left[f_c-\frac B2, f_c+\frac B2\right]$ for positivists, and by integrating $\dfrac{N_0}2$ times the power transfer function $|H(f)|^2$ over $f \in \left[f_c-\frac B2, f_c+\frac B2\right] \bigcup \left[-f_c-\frac B2, -f_c+\frac B2\right]$ for negativists.
And don't believe all that stuff about complex-valued signals being the cause of the discrepancy that the cognoscenti trying to close your question as already having been answered are pointing out to you. Complex-valued signals have nothing to do with the matter.
